# Onchange in select dropdown not working

Tags: html, angularjs, select, drop-down-menu, onchange

hope you fine and well,

i have the following form:

```
<form  class="form-horizontal alert alert-warning" name="testForm" id="testForm" ng-submit="fun2();" hidden>
<h3 class="text-center">New Person</h3>
            <select   class="form-control" id="selPer" onchange="fun2()" >
                  <option ng-repeat="c in persons"  value="{{c.per_id}}">{{c.per_name}}</option>
            </select>       
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="testForm.$invalid">Add Person</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

the form mainly contains select dropdown and a submit button, and i have this function in the controller:

```
myApp.controller("personCtrl",['$scope','$http','myService', function($scope,$http,myService){

$scope.fun2=function(){
    alert();
}
}]);
```

the drop down works well, but the function not work when i change the selection from the drop down menu, but when i click the submit button the function work ! so its work with the button and not working with onchange event, note: when i put the function outside the controller it works with onchange !

what is the problem ?!

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `onchange` attribute to `ng-change`.  You can't access a function in your controller from a regular HTML event.  Angular is expecting you to use an Angularized event (`ng-change`).

That's why the function runs when you submit the form.  You're using `ng-submit` which lets Angular access the function in your Angular controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need a ng-model attribute if you want to catch the change event.

Comment: Your answer is not clear. You could perhaps include an example